# Copying a detailed piece of a mesh and making it conform to the curve of a sphere

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

I'm making a model that has a ton of minuscule detail. I was wondering if there was a shortcut to copying a good detailed piece of my mesh and just pasting it to another section of it?

I've tried duplicating but my mesh is a sphere and at an angle which makes it hard to relocate the duplicate to another section.

[image]

Comment: can you include some images, so we can better uderstand what you are relating to and maybe blend file as well?

Comment: Added image above^

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution lies in the [Array modifier.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html)

Use the Array modifier on your detail, put an empty on the center of your sphere and use it for the Object Offset so that your details will follow the curve of the sphere.